# jQuery not working on mobile devices on Bootstrap websites

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, device

I'm having issues with Bootstrap and jQuery on mobile devices. It's like jQuery cannot be found or something. Everything called after a jQuery-function is not executed.

This is how it's implemented in my HTML:

```
...
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

This is how it's called in my JS:

```
alert('Before jQuery call');
alert(jQuery().jquery);
alert('After jQuery call');
```

The first alert is executed, the rest isn't

Comment: Check with `window.jQuery` ?

Comment: All alerts are executed, I get undefined for alert(window.jQuery);

Comment: Found the issue. Nothing to do with jQuery or Bootstrap script itself. Seems when you download jQuery the access for everyone is set to 'no access'. When I used PHP-Storm build in server everything worked fine, but when I used my localhost itself it gave the same error.

Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0):

Have created the following page that does what you are doing and it works fine

http://jsbin.com/weperarapu/1/

The source is here...

http://jsbin.com/weperarapu/1/edit?html,output

Does it work on the desktop at all?

Check the files were 100% loaded, I have seen JS files not load on my web page because of the way I saved the JS file to my machine and it had the wrong permissions.

If the JS files are loaded I would look at potential issues outside of what you have posted, e.g. Are you seeing any JS errors in your console on the desktop. Is the page valid HTML. Are you trying to do the alert before jquery has been loaded

Do you have a publicly accessible URL at all?

Comment: On desktop everything works fine. I'm having the issue on mobile devices only. I have no public URL (unfortunately)

Comment: Does my example work on your testing mobile? If it does there's likely to be something else in the page being a pain. Try removing any other JS libraries and HTML until you are down to the bare bones like in my example. Also double check you have deployed and are loading the page that you think you are ;-)

Comment: Your example worked on my mobile device which made me thinking.

Found the issue. Nothing to do with jQuery or Bootstrap script itself. Seems when you download jQuery the access for everyone is set to 'no access'. When I used PHP-Storm build in server everything worked fine, but when I used my localhost itself it gave the same error.

Thanks for the time!

Comment: Glad you found the solution, looking at problems from a different angle can help ;-)